# ¿Como optimizar las validaciones en un formulario de registro?

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando un formulario de registro en android, utilizo varios bloques if para hacer las validaciones de cada campo y después insertar la información en una base de datos (Esto ya lo tengo solucionado), me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de optimizar o mejorar  mi código.

```
private void validateForm(View v){

    User u = new User();

    if(!editTextfirstName.getText().toString().equals("") && editTextfirstName.getText().toString().length() >= 3){

        u.setFirstName(editTextfirstName.getText().toString());
        editTextfirstName.setError(null);

    }else {

        editTextfirstName.setError("Nombre(s) invalidos");

    }

    if(!editTextlastName.getText().toString().equals("") && editTextlastName.getText().toString().length() > 3){

        u.setLastName(editTextlastName.getText().toString());
        editTextlastName.setError(null);

    }else{

        editTextlastName.setError("Apellido(s) invalidos");

    }

    if(!editTextEmail.getText().toString().equals("") && editTextEmail.getText().toString().contains("@") && editTextEmail.getText().toString().length() > 5){

        u.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        editTextEmail.setError(null);

    }else{

        editTextEmail.setError("Correo electronico invalido");

    }

    if(!editTextPass.getText().toString().equals("")  && editTextPass.getText().toString().length() >= 5){

        String pw = editTextPass.getText().toString();
        editTextPass.setError(null);
        editTextConfirmPass.setError(null);

        if(editTextConfirmPass.getText().toString().equals(pw)){

            u.setPassword(pw);

        }
        else {
            editTextConfirmPass.setError("Las contaseñas no coinciden");
        }

    }else {

        editTextPass.setError("Contraseña invalida");
        editTextConfirmPass.setError("Contraseña invalida");

    }


    insert(u, v);


}

private void insert(User u, View v){

    if(u.getFirstName() != null && u.getLastName() != null && u.getEmail() != null && u.getPassword() != null){
        myDatabase.addUser(u);

        cleanForm();

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Usuario registrado correctamente", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.show();
    }

}

private void cleanForm(){
    editTextfirstName.setText(null);
    editTextlastName.setText(null);
    editTextEmail.setText(null);
    editTextPass.setText(null);
    editTextConfirmPass.setText(null);
}
```

Comment: Es recomendable usar despues del if, puros else if y por ultimo tu else. y para insertar usas un asynctask ?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
private boolean validateForm(){
    if (condicionErronea) {
        editTextfirstName.setError("Nombre(s) invalidos");
        return false;
    } 
    if (condicionErronea2) {
        editTextlastName.setError("Apellido(s) invalidos");
        return false;
    } 
    if (condicionErronea3) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Correo electronico invalido");
        return false;
    } 

    .
    .
    .

    return true;

}
```

Como dato, no deberías llamar al `insert` si tu `User` puede tener datos `null`

***Método*** `insert`:

```
private void insert(User u, View v){

    myDatabase.addUser(u);

    cleanForm();

    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Usuario registrado correctamente", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    snackbar.show();

}
```

***Proceso principal:***

```
if (validateForm()) {
    //Si llega aquí es que no ha habido ningún error
    User u = new User();
    u.setFirstName(editTextfirstName.getText().toString());
    u.setLastName(editTextlastName.getText().toString());
    u.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    .
    .
    .

    insert(u, v);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si mejor usas `else if` así evitas usar `return` en todos lados?

Comment: ¿Y si quitas los `else if` y pones solo `if`? no hay ningún sentido poner `else if`  si cada `else if` hace `return`

Comment: @centenond Si el `setError` no le para el programa, no utilizar el `return` en cada caso seria un error, ya que podría crear un objeto `User` con datos erróneos

Comment: @cnbandicoot yo no dije que no utilizaras `return` :P

Comment: @centenond Editado!

Comment: @cnbandicoot No, yo no fui el que dijo que no usaras `return` eso fue Luiggi yo dije que no hay necesidad de usar `else if` si haces `return` en cada caso

Comment: pero bueno eso depende de estilo, ami no me agradan mucho los `else if` y los trato de evitar cuando puedo :P

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor reducir el código mediante la ayuda de funciones, por ejemplo agregando una que detecte si el valor contenido en los EditText no es vacio y sea mayor a la longitud requerida:

```
private boolean noNullEmptyOrMinLength(String value, int length){
    if(value != null || !value.isEmpty() || value.length() > length) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

puedes usar el mismo método u otro para validar si contiene el caracter deseado:

```
   private boolean noEmptyOrMinLengthContains(String value, int length, String containValue){
        if((value != null || !value.isEmpty()) && value.length() > length && value.contains(containValue)) { //Se cumple condición.
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

No se podría usar `else if` ya que son diferentes `EditText`, podrías reducir a:

```
if(noNullEmptyOrMinLength(editTextfirstName.getText().toString(), 3)){    
    u.setFirstName(editTextfirstName.getText().toString());
    editTextfirstName.setError(null);    
}else {    
    editTextfirstName.setError("Nombre(s) invalidos");    
}

if((noNullEmptyOrMinLength(editTextlastName.getText().toString(), 3)){    
    u.setLastName(editTextlastName.getText().toString());
    editTextlastName.setError(null);   
}else{    
    editTextlastName.setError("Apellido(s) invalidos");    
}

if(noEmptyOrMinLengthContains(editTextEmail.getText().toString(),5, "@")){
    editTextEmail.setError(null);    
}else{
    editTextEmail.setError("Correo electronico invalido");
}

if((noNullEmptyOrMinLength(editTextPass.getText().toString(), 5)){
    String pw = editTextPass.getText().toString();
    editTextPass.setError(null);
    editTextConfirmPass.setError(null);
    if(editTextConfirmPass.getText().toString().equals(pw)){
        u.setPassword(pw);
    }else {
        editTextConfirmPass.setError("Las contaseñas no coinciden");
    }
}else {
    editTextPass.setError("Contraseña invalida");
    editTextConfirmPass.setError("Contraseña invalida");
}
```